# In Magento 2 is there any chance to broke site due to spaces in di.xml file

Tags: magento2, di.xml

Is there any chance or any cause to broke the site due to spaces in di.xml file in Magento 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If di.xml can be broken the site. But it depends on the code.

if you did the wrong code at di.xml and it related files then the site will be broken.

Most of the cases, the 3rd party modules have created the issue. So you should  disabled that extension one by one Check  which modules are created   the issue.

Comment: I had override contact us, controller, its working fine but in the di.xml file, some lines are commented at the top of the XML file it makes an issue...?

Comment: As this xml files, so, `<?xml ` will be at first line of file.

Comment: <!--<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="test\..\..\..\Post" />
</config> -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="test\..\..\..\Post"/>
</config>

Comment: this is my di.xml file..is it make any issue..?

Comment: Yes, it should create an issue.Please write proper XML file